# JTextField to File Output

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jframe, jtextfield

I'm trying to make a program which the user signs up and his information gets output to a file using simple text output?

Here is my whole class..

```
package malkawi.login;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import malkawi.login.JTextFieldLimit;


/**
 * 
 * @author Defiledx1
 * sign up
 */

public class SignUp extends JFrame implements EventListener {



    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton complete = new JButton("Next");
    JLabel fname = new JLabel("Name: ");
    JLabel Mname = new JLabel("Middle Name: ");
    JLabel Lname = new JLabel("Last Name: ");
    JLabel user = new JLabel("Username: ");
    JLabel pass = new JLabel("Password: ");
    JLabel info = new JLabel("Click Next to Continue");
    JLabel email = new JLabel("Email: ");
    JLabel scode = new JLabel("Secret Code: ");
    JTextField fname1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField Mname1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField Lname1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField user1 = new JTextField();
    JPasswordField pass1 = new JPasswordField();
    JTextField email1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField scode1 = new JTextField();
    JRadioButton showPass = new JRadioButton("Show Pass");


    public SignUp() {
        super("Sign Up - Flare By Malkawi");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 400);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 10, 10));
        setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        /*
         * Limitations
         */
        fname1.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(10));
        Mname1.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(1));
        Lname1.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(10));
        user1.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(15));
        email1.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(80));
        scode1.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(5));
        /*
         * End Of Limitations
         */
        /*
         * RadioButton Checked : Unchecked
         */
        showPass.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
             public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {          
                 showPassword(e.getStateChange() == 1 ? true : false);

             }           
          });
        /*
         * End of RadioButton Checked : UnChecked
         */
        /*
         * Action of registration
         */
          complete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                 try {
                    outPutInformation();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Flare is unable at the moment!");
                }
                }
            }); 
          /*
           * End of Action of registration
           */
          //  Dimension labelSize = info.getPreferredSize();
          /*
           * Start of placements
           */
            //add(info);
            add(fname);
            add(fname1);
            add(Mname);
            add(Mname1);
            add(Lname);
            add(Lname1);
            add(user);
            add(user1);
            add(pass);
            add(pass1);
            add(email);
            add(email1);
            add(scode);
            add(scode1);
            add(complete);
            add(showPass);
            add(info);
            pack();
    }

    public void showPassword(boolean showP) {
        if (showP == true) {
            pass1.setEchoChar((char)0);
        } else {
            pass1.setEchoChar('*');
        }

    }

    /*
     * File Output Requirements
     */
    String filename = user1.getText();
    String firstname = fname1.getText();
    String middlename = Mname1.getText();
    String lastname = Lname1.getText();
    String username = user1.getText();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    String password = pass1.getText();
    String hotmail = email1.getText();
    String secretcode = scode1.getText();
    /*
     * File Output done
     */


    public void outPutInformation() throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filename+".txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println(firstname);
        writer.println(middlename);
        writer.println(lastname);
        writer.println(username);
        writer.println(password);
        writer.println(hotmail);
        writer.println(secretcode);
        writer.close();
    }



}
```

the problem is that it's not outputting anything out.
How is it possible to output the file like 2 folder behind

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not outputting anything because your variables are initialized before entering anything in the text fields. you need to do like this, or directly write textfield values to the file instead if first saving to variables and then writing to file:

```
public void outPutInformation() throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String filename = user1.getText();
    String firstname = fname1.getText();
    String middlename = Mname1.getText();
    String lastname = Lname1.getText();
    String username = user1.getText();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    String password = pass1.getText();
    String hotmail = email1.getText();
    String secretcode = scode1.getText();

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filename+".txt", "UTF-8");
    writer.println(firstname);
    writer.println(middlename);
    writer.println(lastname);
    writer.println(username);
    writer.println(password);
    writer.println(hotmail);
    writer.println(secretcode);
    writer.close();
}
```